# How do I check if a HTML object is null in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to find an object in HTML with jQuery.

```
function getHats() {
    $.get('http://www.roblox.com/User.aspx?ID=1',
        function parse(data) {
            var id1 = $(data).find('#ctl00_cphRoblox_rbxUserAssetsPane_UserAssetsDataList_ctl09_AssetThumbnailHyperLink');
            hatname1 = id1.attr('title');
            hatlink1 = "http://www.roblox.com" + id1.attr('href');
            hatpic1 = id1.find('img').attr('src');
            var lim1 = id1.parent('.AssetThumbnail').find('div');
            if(!lim1) {
                hatlim1 = true;
                alert("Null")
            }else{
                hatlim1 = false;
            };
        }
    );
};
```

It always pops up the alert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use length - but you don't have to be explicit about it:

```
if (lim1.length) {
    // lim1 has a length! And it's not 0!
} else {
    // arg, lim1 has a length of 0
}
```

Equivalently, the negation operator `!` will work fine.

```
if (!lim1.length) {
    // arg!
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can use `length`.

```
if(lim1.length < 1){
    //alert 
}
```